# Error in encoding string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, encoding

This might be a very simple problem but i am just not able to solve it.

In my python console I do :

```
request.request.data.get('comment')
```

I get `{u'price': u'21', u'unit': u'30\xd730', u'name': u'test', u'comments': u'check'}`

The value of comment originally is :

```
            "comments" : "check",
            "name" : "test",
            "price" : "21",
            "unit" : "30×30"(multiplication sign x)
```

How can I solve this such that I get `request.request.data.get('comment')` as `{u'price': u'21', u'unit': u'30x30', u'name': u'test', u'comments': u'check'}`?

I tried using:

```
request.request.data.get('comment').get('unit').encode('utf-8')
```

but it returns `'30\xc3\x9730'`

I want to convert `/xd` to ascii.

Comment: use `str` function to get string

  `str(request.request.data.get('comment'))`

Comment: {u'price': u'21', u'unit': u'30\\xd730', u'name': u'test', u'comments': u'check'} got this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a feature (bug?) in methods

```
dict.__repr__()
```

and/or

```
dict.__str__()
```

of Python 2.7.x. Really all is Ok. You can check it by

```
print a[u'unit']
```

which prints

```
30x30
```

P.S. No problems in Python 3.5.2...

See below interactive session of Python 2.7 in unicode Pycharm console:

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> a=u'\xd7'
>>> a
u'\xd7'
>>> print a
×
```

Comment: comment['unit'] doesn't work for my code. It gives `comment['unit'] = 
u'30\xd730'`

Comment: print function may print it as a normal string but i am using str(comment.get('unit')) kind of thing

Comment: In Python 2.7 str is just a sequence of bytes... No encoding, etc... That's why you see escape symbols. I think you will get UnicodeEncodeError in str(comment.get('unit'))

Comment: Just remove str(...), because its argument is a Unicode object with multiplication symbol \xd7 which can't be automatically converted to ASCII, and use print to show results to the users of your program. Or use Python 3.x if possible.

Answer (score 0):

u'something' is just the python way to display unicode character string in a list or a dict or a tuple.

If you print the value to the string itself (`print request.request.data.get('comment').get('unit')`), you get the actual characters.

Except if your terminal does not support it (or if python thinks so).
You can try to use codecs module to force a particular encoding :

```
sys.stdout=codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
```